# Rave Reports exporting to excel

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

i have a rave report with 5 pages inside it, we need to export to excel two page from those 5 report pages, each page is a report itself... we use gnostice v2.5 to do the exporting. 
  currently using Rave 6.5 with BDS2006.

Hi, maybe i was not clear enough, i have 1 Report which consists of 5 pages, Page1,    Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5, each page work as a differente report, i can export the entire report without a problem, bu we only need to export Page1 and Page2. and yes my question is how do i do it? Thanks.

thanks,
  Vladimir

Comment: And the question is? I assume you want to know how to do this?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Could you just export the _data_ to Excel and skip the report? Exporting data from Delphi to Excel is a solved problem that you should be able to find many demonstrations of.

Answer (score 0):

Whith Rave you have the possibility to generate some reports ending up in one printjob (See [tipp #41](http://nevrona.com/Products/RaveReports/TipsTricks/TipsRaveGeneral/Tip041MultipleReportsinSinglePrintJob/tabid/122/Default.aspx) at Nevrona.com). So you could split your Report in one report per page and print them normally together - or generating the desired pages for your excel export.

Regards Klaus

Comment: Hi, maybe i was not clear enough, i have 1 Report which consists of 5 pages, Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5, each page work as a differente report, i can export the entire report without a problem, bu we only need to export Page1 and Page2. and yes my question is how do i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far I remember, the report must not pass through the 5 pages. So, you have to manipulate the report change page sequence to make sure that the report rendering won't pass pages 1 and 2.

You can do that configuring parameters and interpreting them on scripts inside the report itself - allowing auto-config of it.

I don't remember of seeing something about exporting just a fraction of the report.